# The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource - submit button to make a search

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to search through a table in the database and return the values on button click. This is the form that contains the search button

```
<div class="form-group">    
                          <form action="searchT">
                              <label class=" control-label col-sm-2">No</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"> <input class="form-control" type='text' name='searchName' id='searchName'/> </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Validate'/></div>
                          </form>
                         </div>
```

This is the controller

```
@RequestMapping("searchT")
    public ModelAndView searchTOE(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {  
        logger.info("Searching the T: "+searchName);
        List<TOE> tinList = TOEService.getAllTins(searchName);
        return new ModelAndView("serviceDescription", "tList", tList);      
    }
```

This is the error response when I click the submit button

```
type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you make a post request through your form and then in the controller you expect a get request.

Try something like this in the front end and tell me if this worked for you
change

```
<form action="searchT" >
```

to

```
<form action="searchT" method="get">
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No q
ualifying bean of type [net.service.datastore.Individual_S
ervice]

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not au
towire field: private net.service.datastore.Ser
vice net.controller._Individual_Controller.Service; n

Comment: if you put a breakpoint does it go through this line logger.info("Searching the T: "+searchName);

Comment: I am deploying it to tomcat as a war file.

Comment: can you test is locally?

Comment: In the logs do you see now "Searching the T: " and the value that you enter in the input box?

Comment: Except the change that I just suggested (changing the form action to get) did you make any other changes?

Comment: Yeah. is not from ur changes

Comment: So, If my answer solved the problem that you have asked can you mark it as solved and start another question with the errors that you are facing now?

Comment: I was about trying your answer before this error came up.

Comment: Can you revert the changes that you have made (up to the point that you have asked this question) and let me know if this works?

Comment: I have done that and still the code is failing. I just want to raise a new ticket and come back to this solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266141/error-creating-bean-with-name-individual-controller-injection-of-autowired-de

Comment: Are you there? I am back to this stage

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not
supported